# Action bar is not visible in new Android Studio version

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I'm a beginner in android studio and was trying to create my first project but Action bar is not visible in new Android Studio version. Please suggest some ways so that I can show the action bar in my android project.
All the elements are visible except the action bar.
I just want to show the action bar in my android project.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add it to your layout. This is the code for a general Toolbar. How you add it to your layout, depends on the root layout you use (`CoordinatorLayout`, `FrameLayout`, `LinearLayout`, ...).

```xml
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/toolbarBackground">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.MaterialToolbar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check if you are using the correct theme.

Try with `Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar` or similar themes with actionbar instead of your current theme. eg: `Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar`

Kindly check your theme in themes.xml file, see the example below

`<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.DayNight.DarkActionBar"/>`

Comment: Thanks man !! Action bar color is BLACK. It is not Blue. Still thanks a lot for your hep.